# Update packages in a ASP.NET Core 2.0 Angular Web Application

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017, package.json

I create a new Web Application project (ASP.NET Core 2.0, Angular template) with Visual Studio 2017 15.4.4.

This template comes with Angular 4.2.5 packages and I'd like to update them to a newer version.

I tried a couple of things:

- Using the 'Bower Package Manager' of Visual Studio. But the package manager does not show any installed packages.
- Using the 'Update Package' Quick Action in the *package.json* file. I can see something happening in the Bower/npm console of Visual Studio, but the package version in *package.json* does not change.
- Manually change the version of a package in *package.json* and save it. Again I can see something happening in the Bower/npm console, but looking at the packages in the *node_modules* folder shows that the packages were not actually updated.
- Manually change the version of a package in *package.json*, closing Visual Studio, deleting the node_modules folder, rebuild solution. I can see that all packages are being restored, but still with version 4.2.5 and not with the version I specified in *package.json*.

This is with a fresh project based on the Angular template.

What is the correct way to update these packages?

Answer (score 0):

I have configured angular 5.0 with material design  using vs2015. 
so try with below steps..

[Click Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cTfxAeyCipQxZGEFqvyU?p=preview) You will found listed file code help.

Step1: create below files and copy and paste code.

```
  a) package.json
  b) tsconfig.json
  c) system.config.js
```

Step2: Bind on _Layout.cshtml head tag part

Step3: create main.ts file

Step4: create module.ts file

Step5: create component.ts file

Step6: Bind component selector in index.cshtml (get code from index.html) page